# Create IMAP/POP3 accounts programmatically

Tags: java, android, account

I can add a Gmail account by codes using **Accountmanager** in my Android application. But IMAP/POP3 accounts are slightly different.

How can I add IMAP/POP3 accounts by programming?

Comment: can you please add explain how to add a gmail account via AccountManager ?

Answer (score -1):

This is pretty much the same answer as for [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640496/how-to-get-imap-pop3-accounts):

Step #1: Make a list of all IMAP/POP3 capable email clients for Android. There are probably several dozen.

Step #2: Iterate over that list, contacting each developer, and asking them whether there is an API for manipulating account information for their app.